# Hard drive stalls and the head massively starts clicking after random amounts of times

Tags: hard-drive

I have a WD Blue HDD (WD10EZEX) 1 TB, which I started using after 5 years of it being completely out of the box.

1.The head was writing stuffs perfectly fine until it reaches a suspicious sector where it would stall very hard and writes at from around hundred bytes to hundred kilobytes per sec. [Here is the noise the head does during the stall.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/820150874185007124/919825010871378001/rec_2021-12-13_00-35-17.wav)

[And here is where it stalls](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/820150874185007124/919825250672324638/IMG_20211213_003654.jpg)(given the fact I'm copying a single ISO file)

[The HDD in question:](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/673535439889760306/915569852905828352/IMG_20211201_171930.jpg)

I know that bad sectors are normally ignored during the ongoing write activity but this is just oddly wrong. And for the noise I gave above, what exactly does it indicate?

2.[After another attempt of trying to write another file on the same sector, it ended up being exactly 1024 MB big...?](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/820150874185007124/919845795166056448/IMG_20211213_015735.jpg)

Once again I'll summarize the issue here: Drive stalls at a sector when copying files (second highlight), outputting oddly weird noises (first highlight) and ends up corrupting the files at the same sector (last highlight). All I need is what the noise (first highlight) indicates during the stall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Clicking drive is dying drive. Replace immediately.

Comment: Well if that's so then I probably will try to retrieve whatever left it has before dumping the thing.